# Show that $f'\left(\frac13\right)$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Consider the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}
    x^2\left|\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2x}\right|, &x\ne 0\\
    0, & x=0
  \end{cases}$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    x^2\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2x}, &\dfrac{\pi}{2x}\in\left[2n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{2},2n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]\\
       -x^2\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2x}, &\dfrac{\pi}{2x}\in\left(2n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2},2n\pi+\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right)\\
    0, & x=0
  \end{cases}$$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    x^2\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2x}, &x\in\left[\dfrac{1}{4n+1},\dfrac{1}{4n-1}\right]\\
       -x^2\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2x}, &x\in\left(\dfrac{1}{4n+3},\dfrac{1}{4n+1}\right)\\
    0, & x=0
  \end{cases}$$

$$f'\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{3}+h\right)^2\cos\left(\dfrac{3\pi}{2(1+3h)}\right)}{h}$$

$$f'\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{h}+9h+6\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{3\pi}{2(1+3h)}\right)}{9}$$

$$f'\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac{3\pi}{2(1+3h)}\right)}{9h}+\lim_{h\to0}h\cos\left(\dfrac{3\pi}{2(1+3h)}\right)+\dfrac{2}{3}\lim_{h\to0}\cos\left(\dfrac{3\pi}{2(1+3h)}\right)$$

$$f'\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac{3\pi}{2(1+3h)}\right)}{9h}$$

Assuming $\dfrac{1}{1+3h}=y$, as $h\rightarrow 0, \dfrac{1}{1+3h}\rightarrow 1,h=\dfrac{1-y}{3y}$

$$f'\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=\lim_{y\to1}\dfrac{y\cos\left(\dfrac{3\pi y}{2}\right)}{3(1-y)}$$

Applying L'Hospital as we have $\dfrac{0}{0}$ determinant form

$$f'\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=\lim_{y\to1}\dfrac{-y\sin\left(\dfrac{3\pi y}{2}\right)\dfrac{3\pi}{2}+\cos\left(\dfrac{3\pi y}{2}\right)}{-3}$$

$$f'\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

It seems function is differentiable at $\dfrac{1}{3}$, what am I missing here?

Comment: You forgot about the absolute value along the way.

Comment: sorry I didn't get, where?

Comment: In the definition there is an absolute value. Then, when you write the formula for $f'(1/3)$, you write it using the formula for $f$, but only the formula for $f$, without absolute value, that is valid on one side of $h=0$. You used the formula, for $n=1$, which is valid on the left of $1/3$, on $[1/5,1/3]$.

Comment: if you see I have opened that function and written the value according to it.

Comment: But for $h\to0^+$, then you need to use the formula for $f$ that is valid on $[1/3,1]$. On this side the formula looks similar, but for a $-$ sign in front. You can do all the same computations, but on this side that $-$ is going to be applied to the final result. So, you will get $+\pi/2$.

Comment: ok got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a derivative to exist, the right hand derivative must be equal to the left hand derivative. 
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$$

Also the limits for defining functions will be $[\frac{1}{4n+1},\frac{1}{4n-1}] \text{ and }(\frac{1}{4n+3},\frac{1}{4n+1})$

For $x=1/3$, the left hand derivative will use the last part of the equation while the right handed derivative will use the second part of the equation. You just evaluated the second part. Also evaluate $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$ using the definition for $f(1/3-h)=-(1/3-h)^2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2(1/3-h)})$and you'll see they're not equal